# While Loop in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to calculate a "total days taken" to complete a project. However, each project can have the same project code for each day.

Project A (project code associated: 123abc)

```
 project code 123abc: [comment] "starting to clean", [startdate]: 01/01/2022, [enddate]: 01/01/2022, + other variables

 project code 123abc: [comment] "finished cleaning, painting", [startdate]: 01/02/2022, [enddate]: 01/03/2022+ other variables

 project code 123abc: [comment] "paint and clean finished", [startdate]: 01/04/2022, [enddate]: 01/05/2022+ other variables
```

Goal is to see `Total Days Completed" for Project A: **4** days`

Can Spotfire calculate this somehow, considering multiple project codes that are under the same code? Or is there a while loop that can be made to evaluate "while (project code is the same), [Day Count] ++" ?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways in which you could calculate it. You don't specify you want it in a column or a separate view for instance.

If you want a calculated column, you could have a [Project duration] as:

```
DateDiff('day',Min([startdate]) over ([project_code]),Max([enddate]) over ([project_code]))
```

If you want a separate summary view, you could use a KPI visualization, and set up a KPI with Values:

```
Value:  DateDiff('day',Min([startdate]),Max([enddate]))
Tile by: project_code
```

You don't say what you want to do with the additional variables, but you could use them to slice the calculation, so instead of

```
over ([project_code])
```

you could do for the calculated column

```
over (Intersect([project_code],[other_variable1],[other_variable2]))
```

and tile the KPI over the additional variables.

There are resources on YouTube (e.g. the Dr Spotfire series) to help with the Over functionality in Spotfire.

Comment: The KPI visualization may be helpful. I have not tried that yet. However, the calculated column says that the expression is not valid for the code : DateDiff('day',Min([startdate]) over ([project_code]),Max([enddate]) over ([project_code]))

Comment: have you checked that the startdate and enddate are stored as dates and not strings? What is the error (you should see it if you hover)

Answer (score 0):

This was a trial/error way of finding the answer, but this worked on both KPI visualizations, calculated columns, and bar charts:

DateDiff("day",Min([startdate]),Max([enddate]))

This will consider all counted days for each unique project code.

Comment: I thought this was my answer...? If so, can you accept it. Thanks